# Persistence Entity must not be null

Tags: spring-data-rest

with following code I am getting error Persistence entity must not be null. what could be the mistake.

```
public interface DistrictRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<District, Integer> {

    @Query(
            "select d.districtId, d.districtName from District d where d.districtId in (:districtIds) group by d.districtId"
    )
    @RestResource(path="byList")
    List<Object[]> byList(@Param("districtIds") List<Integer> districtIds);
}
```

Comment: Some Entity you are trying to persist is null, maybe the list districtIds or one of its entries?

Comment: list districtIds is not null. If I change query to "select d from District d where d.districtId in (:districtIds) group by d.districtId" and return type to List<District>, it works

Comment: I think spring data rest cannot expose some properties like this. I have tried to use the same method from within a controller and return the response. it works!!!

Comment: As I see you are using `@RestResource(path="byList")`, so you want to public this method as "search" one? But how are you going to pass a list of parameters to its endpoint? Or you are going to use this method just in your custom controller?

Comment: if i use this method in controller, it works. I want to make it work directly. I am passing list of parameters as http://localhost:8080/api/districts/search/byList?districtIds=1,2,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to make a "search" method, use this approach:

```java
@Projection(name = "idAndName", types = {District.class})
public interface IdAndName {
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
}

@RestResource(path="byIds", rel="byIds")
@Query("select d from District d where d.districtId in (:districtIds)")
List<District> findByIds(@Param("ids") Integer... ids);
```

Then use this url:

```text
http://localhost:8080/api/districts/search/byIds?ids=1,2,3&projection=idAndName
```

More info about [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections)

If you need to use complex queries with grouping and aggregation that return DTOs you can not use "search" methods. Instead you have to implement [custom controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers), for example:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/districts")
public class DistrictController {

    @Autoware
    private DistrictRepo repo;

    @GetMapping("/report")
    public ResponseEntity<?> report(@RequestParam(value = "ids") Integer... ids) {
        List<Dto> dtos = repo.getDtosByIds(ids);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources<>(dtos));
    }
}
```

Where `Dto` is something like this:

```java
@Data // This is Lombok annotation (https://projectlombok.org/)
@Relation(value = "district", collectionRelation = "districts")
public class Dto {

    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;
}
```

And something like this the repo method:

```java
public interface DistrictRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<District, Integer> {

    @Query("select new ...Dto(d.districtId, d.districtName) from District d where d.districtId in (:districtIds) group by d.districtId")
    @RestResource(path="byList", rel="byList")
    List<Dto> getDtosByIds(@Param("ids") Integer... ids);
}
```

More [info](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select_clause).

Comment: first approach is not usefull as i want to group and add a column for summation in the final response. Tried second approach, still same error.

Comment: @ArslanAnjum 1) It's just example - you can provide custom query with aggregation and grouping. 2) You didn't specify where exactly you have got an error - show more your code. 3) And where do you want to use this method - as "search" method or to use it in your custom controller just to get DTOs?