# Custom ResourceAssembler for Spring Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I created a Spring Boot 2 application using Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS, Hibernate.

I'd like to create a custom ResourceAssembler. I accomplished to that creating this bean:

```
@Component
public class StringResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<String, Resource<String>> {

    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Override
    public Resource<String> toResource(String question) {
        Resource<String> resource = new Resource<String>(question);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

I need a customer ResourceAssembler because in Spring Repository I've this method:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface FrameRepository extends JpaRepository<Frame, Long> {

     @Transactional(readOnly = true)
     @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT f.manufacturer FROM Frame f WHERE :searchString IS NULL OR (f.manufacturer LIKE CONCAT(:searchString,'%')) GROUP BY f.manufacturer ORDER BY f.manufacturer")
     public Page<String> manufacturerAutocomplete(@Param("searchString") String searchString, Pageable pageable);
```

As you can see my method is exported by Spring Data REST and it returs a page of String values (I've the same problem with enumerations).

Unfortunately I've this exception:

```
15/11/2018 12:09:45,054 ERROR http-nio-8082-exec-7 RepositoryRestExceptionHandler:168 - Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:72) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:38) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.createResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:208) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.lambda$entitiesToResources$3(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:95) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:95) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:78) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toResource$1(RepositorySearchController.java:209) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toResource(RepositorySearchController.java:206) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:190) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Is there a way to make my ResourceAssembler working with Spring Data REST?

Comment: Why you are adding @Param("searchString") String searchString while its not used into query?

Comment: @RaheelaAslam my bad, I forgot a part of the query. But that's not the point of the question.

Comment: Some how your issue is due to Page<String> you need to get Page<Object> then type cast to String.
Or you can get String result into a custom DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository extends from `JpaRepository<Frame, Long>`, so it expects a `Page<Frame>`, not a `Page<String>`.

Comment: I don't see the problem in having a method/query returning something different from an object (in my case Frame). The problem seems to be rather how to attach a custom ResourceAssembler to my repository.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a class in which you want to save result.

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Result {
        private String manufacturer;
    }
```

> RepositoryMethod:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = "SELECT New Result(DISTINCT f.manufacturer) FROM Frame f WHERE :searchString IS NULL OR (f.manufacturer LIKE CONCAT(:searchString,'%')) GROUP BY f.manufacturer ORDER BY f.manufacturer")
public Page<Result> manufacturerAutocomplete(@Param("searchString") String searchString, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I've the same identical excption I've with String. The only difference is Spring complains about "Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class test.Result!"

Comment: Can you Please change the Page to List<Result> and try ?

Comment: Please also look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231260/persistence-entity-must-not-be-null.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I think I'm going with a custom controller. It's longer and it's odd I need to do that though.